# What is wrong with this ANDEngine HUD?

Tags: andengine, hud

I am trying to make a HUD at AndEngine, but when I write this code below and run the emulator, only thing appears on Emulator is a black screen with crashed HUD image.

This is what I want to display,[image]
and This is how my code show.

[image] This is my code -

```html
package com.example.andenginetester;


import org.andengine.engine.camera.Camera;
import org.andengine.engine.camera.hud.HUD;
import org.andengine.engine.options.EngineOptions;
import org.andengine.engine.options.ScreenOrientation;
import org.andengine.engine.options.resolutionpolicy.RatioResolutionPolicy;
import org.andengine.entity.scene.Scene;
import org.andengine.entity.scene.background.Background;
import org.andengine.entity.sprite.Sprite;
import org.andengine.opengl.texture.atlas.bitmap.BitmapTextureAtlas;
import org.andengine.opengl.texture.atlas.bitmap.BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory;
import org.andengine.opengl.texture.region.TextureRegion;
import org.andengine.ui.activity.SimpleBaseGameActivity;


public class SpriteTester extends SimpleBaseGameActivity {

 public static final int CAMERA_WIDTH = 720;
 public static final int CAMERA_HEIGHT = 480;
 
 private HUD myHUD;
 
 private Sprite myHUDSprite;
 
 private BitmapTextureAtlas myAtlas;
 private TextureRegion myHUDImage;
 final Camera camera = new Camera(0, 0, CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT); 
 
 @Override
 public EngineOptions onCreateEngineOptions() {


  return new EngineOptions(true, ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE_FIXED, new RatioResolutionPolicy(CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT), camera);
 }


 @Override
 protected void onCreateResources() {
  myAtlas = new BitmapTextureAtlas(this.getTextureManager(), 1024, 1024);
  myHUDImage = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(this.myAtlas, this, "gfx/HUD.png", 0, 0);
  mEngine.getTextureManager().loadTexture(myAtlas);
  
 }

 @Override
 protected Scene onCreateScene() {
  final Scene scene = new Scene();
  scene.setBackground(new Background(0, 0, 0));
  myHUDSprite = new Sprite(0, 0, myHUDImage, this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
  
  myHUD.attachChild(myHUDSprite);
  camera.setHUD(myHUD);
  return scene;

 }
 

 
 

}
```

How I should fix it?

Comment: can you share the picture/ error ?

Comment: @ranifisch I want to share, but it needs 10 reputations....

Comment: Btw, have you tried to work on your real device?

Comment: @ranifisch It is also same in Galaxy Note too. I just tried it

Comment: What version of AndEngine are you using? Where is your HUD Initialization?

Comment: @ranifisch It says AndEngine-GLES2, and I downloaded it from andengine.net

Comment: @ranifisch I added how it shows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I managed to get the correct result , let me know if it works for you:

a) I updated the AndroidManifest.xml

Added in the `<activity ... >`:

1)  `android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|mcc|mnc"`

2)  `android:screenOrientation="landscape"`

b) The updated activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends SimpleBaseGameActivity {

    public static final int CAMERA_WIDTH = 720;
    public static final int CAMERA_HEIGHT = 480;

    private HUD myHUD = new HUD();

    private Sprite myHUDSprite;

    private BitmapTextureAtlas myAtlas;
    private TextureRegion myHUDImage;
    final Camera camera = new Camera(0, 0, CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT);

    @Override
    public EngineOptions onCreateEngineOptions() {

        return new EngineOptions(true, ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE_FIXED,
                new RatioResolutionPolicy(CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT), camera);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreateResources() {
        myAtlas = new BitmapTextureAtlas(this.getTextureManager(), 1024, 1024);
        myHUDImage = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(
                this.myAtlas, this, "gfx/HUD.png", 0, 0);
        mEngine.getTextureManager().loadTexture(myAtlas);

    }

    @Override
    protected Scene onCreateScene() {
        final Scene scene = new Scene();
        scene.setBackground(new Background(0, 0, 0));
        myHUDSprite = new Sprite(0, 0, myHUDImage,
                this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());

        myHUD.attachChild(myHUDSprite);
        myHUD.setPosition(CAMERA_WIDTH/2,CAMERA_HEIGHT/2);
        camera.setHUD(myHUD);
        return scene;

    }

}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, result is same.

Comment: <activity android:name="SpriteTester">
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|mcc|mnc"
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

Comment: Weird.. you just get a black screen? what does the Logcat say?

Comment: 11-04 23:58:53.391: E/AndEngine(6165):  at org.andengine.ui.activity.SimpleBaseGameActivity.onCreateResources(SimpleBaseGameActivity.java:43)
11-04 23:58:53.391: E/AndEngine(6165):  at org.andengine.ui.activity.BaseGameActivity.onCreateGame(BaseGameActivity.java:181)
11-04 23:58:53.391: E/AndEngine(6165):  at org.andengine.ui.activity.BaseGameActivity.onSurfaceCreated(BaseGameActivity.java:110)
11-04 23:58:53.391: E/AndEngine(6165):  at org.andengine.opengl.view.EngineRenderer.onSurfaceCreated(EngineRenderer.java:80)

Comment: 11-04 23:58:53.391: E/AndEngine(6165):  at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1494)
11-04 23:58:53.391: E/AndEngine(6165):  at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1240)

These are all errors.

Comment: Okay, from line 53 in your class, there's NullPointerException, you  didn't initialize your HUD. add this : HUD hud = new HUD();